# HP dv6 2020sa // battery?

Tags: 12.04, hp, battery, dv6

I got to understand that HP dv6 series aren't the best choice for ubuntu. 
The problem is the battery. If I disconnect the cable everything dies instantaneously. 
What can I do ?

I suppose you'll ask me something like this:

```
$> upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 07 Dec 2013 04:52:16 PM CET (12 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         47.52 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47.52 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
```

Many thanks (in advance)!

Comment: Are you certain it's not the battery that is the issue?

Comment: You mean a "dead" battery ? I cannot know for sure, it is a second-hand computer.
Is there a way to check that ? If not, I can try to buy a new one, but I'd rather be sure first.

thanks

Comment: Start the computer and unplug it from the wall, if it dies immediately or within a couple minutes the battery is dead...

Comment: Is it that simple ? Ok that would make sense. Actually I can't even boot at all. Maybe I did not want to see this possibility. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery has probably bit the dust, if you unplug from AC power (a wall outlet) and the computer shuts off immediately or relatively fast (within a few minutes) you can assume the battery needs replaced with relative certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Some batteries - some Chinese in particular - will not charge with simply plugging in the power supply.  You have to power off, take the battery out, and then put it right back in.  When you boot, it will charge, but as it runs down, near the end, you have to do this again. I dscovered this trick by accident; I was going to buy a new battery, so took the old one out to get a number off it.  I put it in, booted so I could use it, and it was charging.

New (Chinese) batteries are only a few dollars.  Even if yours isn't dead, it will be someday, so this isn't a bad thing to have on hand.